# rel attributes - when to use prev or next for paginated timeline?

Tags: html, twitter, pagination, attributes, rel

I have a paginated list of Tweets.  At the bottom is each page are "older" and "newer" links.

People tend to start reading Tweets with the newest and then work backwards.

Should the "older" link have the attribute `rel="prev"` or `rel="next"`?

It is the "next" thing that people will want to read, but it is logically previous.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the expectation is next would be older post - although as you pointed out in semantic terms a bit backwards but this is in terms of an index placement and not a time line on my site I allow the user to select order
new - old  or old- New  so next and previous reflect the users preferred method of traversal but the default expectation is new to old

Hope this helps

-Joshua Joseph Bissot